# How to define a variable with another variable value

Tags: javascript, html, date, variables

I have a list of variables with dates as variable names like a290322, a300322, a310322 etc..

```
var a270322 = "https://google.com" ;
var a280322 = "https://youtube.com" ;
var a290322 = "https://facebook.com" ;
var a300322 = "https://twitter.com" ;
var a310322 = "https://instagram.com" ;
var a010422 = "https://sgquizdaily.com" ;
var a020422 = "https://maps.google.com" ;
var a030422 = "https://gmail.com" ;
var a040422 = "https://docs.google.com" ;
```

Now I want to declare a new variable named **Today**

The value of **Today** variable should match to the variable from the list of variables.

Manually day by day I can modify line like below.

```
var today = a300322 ;
```

But I don't know how to get it by script.

Can you help in assigning today dated variable value to **Today**?

Comment: You can use the function `eval`: you can choose the string, and then the eval will evaluate the constructed string (so with dynamic variable names). But I think you should change method. just have variable a, and `a['270322'] = 'https://site1'`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the current date through Date(), padding to 2 digits, slicing last two, prepend with 'a' and [eval](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/is-javascripts-eval-evil/#:%7E:text=eval()%20is%20evil%20if,input%20crafted%20by%20the%20client.).

```js
var a270322 = "https://google.com" ;
var a280322 = "https://youtube.com" ;
var a290322 = "https://facebook.com" ;
var a300322 = "https://twitter.com" ;
var a310322 = "https://instagram.com" ;
var a010422 = "https://sgquizdaily.com" ;
var a020422 = "https://maps.google.com" ;
var a030422 = "https://gmail.com" ;

const now = new Date()
var day = ('0' + now.getDate()).slice(-2)
var month = ('0' +(now.getMonth() + 1).toString()).slice(-2)
var year = (now.getFullYear().toString()).slice(-2)
var Today = 'a'+ day + month + year
console.log(Today)

TodaysUrl = eval(Today)
console.log(TodaysUrl)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can store the variable into an object so you can store and call the value based on the key like this

```
var a270322 = "https://google.com" ;
var a280322 = "https://youtube.com" ;
var a290322 = "https://facebook.com" ;
var a300322 = "https://twitter.com" ;
var a310322 = "https://instagram.com" ;
var a010422 = "https://sgquizdaily.com" ;
var a020422 = "https://maps.google.com" ;
var a030422 = "https://gmail.com" ;
var a040422 = "https://docs.google.com" ;

const variables = {
  a270322,
  a280322,
  a290322,
  a300322,
  a310322,
  a010422,
  a020422,
  a030422,
  a040422,
};

var today = 'a300322';

console.log(variables[today]); // https://twitter.com
```

Comment: Sorry that's not answered, you have manually defined today variable. But I want it by script. Because it's value for today is **a300322**  but it should automatically be changed to **a310322** for tomorrow. Thank You